# Pubnub Chat APi is calling none SSL request even my site is on https

Tags: javascript, api, pubnub

Mixed Content: The page at '' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint ''. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I have Min.js file of pubnub api.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is that you must init PubNub with `ssl:true`.

```
var pubnub = new PubNub({
    subscribeKey: "mySubscribeKey",
    publishKey: "myPublishKey",
    ssl: (('https:' == document.location.protocol) ? true : false)
});
```

Or just simply set `ssl:true`.

Here's [an article that discusses it](https://support.pubnub.com/support/discussions/topics/14000006213).